# Elastic Beanstalk and Docker launch error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I currently have a docker image that works fine privately hosted.
Inside the container I run an ASP.NET Web API Core application.

AWS has NGINX and is returning me this error when Elastic Beanstalk has started and sometimes when I upload a new version of my application. Anyone able to point out what I am doing wrong?

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2017/09/27 12:02:53 [emerg] 3161#0: no host in upstream "docker" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf:21
```

This is my Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1"
}
```

.ebextensions/00_nginx.config file

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy-timeout.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
           upstream docker {
              server 127.0.0.1:52940;
              keepalive 360;
           }
           client_max_body_size 100G;
           proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
           proxy_send_timeout 3600;
           proxy_read_timeout 3600;
           client_body_timeout 3600;
           client_header_timeout 360;
           send_timeout 3600;
           keepalive_timeout 360;

container_commands:
    01-restart-nginx:
        command: /sbin/service nginx restart
```

and my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
LABEL name "<my_application>"
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:52940
EXPOSE 52940
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<my_application>.dll"]
COPY out .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upstream` are application at `http` block level and the include your create is going at server level. `http` level includes go in `conf.d` directory and `server` level includes go in `sites-available`

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
           upstream docker {
              server 127.0.0.1:52940;
              keepalive 360;
           }
    "/etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy-timeout.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
           client_max_body_size 100G;
           proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
           proxy_send_timeout 3600;
           proxy_read_timeout 3600;
           client_body_timeout 3600;
           client_header_timeout 360;
           send_timeout 3600;
           keepalive_timeout 360;

container_commands:
    01-restart-nginx:
        command: /sbin/service nginx restart
```